# App Store search results

Tags: iphone, ipad

I'm having hard time getting proper results out of app store search.

What I do is:
using their API (ex url: itunes(dot)apple(dot)com/search?term=music&media=all&country=us&callback=usagerj&limit=10&entity=iPadSoftware

and I'm trying to match it with my ipad's results and sadly they are totally different.

For additional test I use same url and check the results with:
searchman(dot)com/ios/search/US/en/?d=iPad&q=music
and again, totally different.

Can anyone help me with this matter?